# Obtain NSString from NSData arriving separately

Tags: objective-c, encoding, nsstring, nsdata

I'm writing a program which converts NSData to NSString with multi-byte encoding.
Conversion itself is easy but the problem is that NSData is arriving separately (The data arrives in order).
Its like

```
- (void) dataArrived:(NSData*) data{
    NSString* mystr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSShiftJISStringEncoding] autorelease];
    // I want to parse string here and show some view as it arrives.
}
```

If the data contains only 8bit letters its ok but I'm parsing multi-byte string data. So what I want to do is converting NSData to NSString from head and keep the invalid bytes to next call of dataArrived (last 1 byte may be left as invalid byte for NSShiftJISStringEncoding since SJIS letter is 1 or 2 bytes).

I wonder if they have any useful method or function for doing this.
Ideal method may take NSData and Encoding and return the position where it finds invalid byte sequence in NSData.

Comment: Doesn't my answer address your question? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Shift JIS is encoded on 1 or 2 bytes, you can assume that:

- either all the unprocessed data are a valid Shift JIS string
- or the first length-1 bytes are a valid Shift JIS string

So, we can use a `NSMutableData` buffer and process the data like this:

```
- (void)dataArrived:(NSData*)data
{
    [_mutableData appendData:data];
    NSUInteger length = [_mutableData length];
    NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_mutableData
                                              encoding:NSShiftJISStringEncoding] autorelease];

    if ( ! string && length )
    {
        // try without the last byte
        --length;
        string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data.bytes
                                           length:length
                                         encoding:NSShiftJISStringEncoding] autorelease];
    }

    if ( ! string && length )
    {
        // we have a problem: the data are invalid
        return;
    }

    // remove processed bytes
    [_mutableData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, length) withBytes:NULL length:0];

    // now, we can append string
}
```

Comment: This looks OK for SJIS encoding. I wanted general solution for any encodings but I use this for SJIS which is currently I'm working on.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no elegant general solution. As most encodings use between 1 and 4 bytes to encode characters, you can loop until you get a valid string or length is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered collecting all of the data and then decoding it all at once?  This would be much simpler than your proposed approach if you don't have to deal with large amounts of data.

Comment: Yes. As I already commented another answer waiting for all the data coming may take long and I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

What about storing all received data, and then recreating the string from the updated data?

```
@interface StringReceiver {
    NSMutableData *_allData;
}
@property (retain, readonly) NSString *string;
- (void)processData:(NSData *)d;
@end

@implementation StringReceiver
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
        _allData = [NSMutableData new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_allData release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSString *)string {
    NSString *s;
    s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_allData encoding:NSShiftJISStringEncoding];
    return [s autorelease];
}

- (void)processData:(NSData *)myData {
    [_allData appendData:myData];
}
@end
```

Now every time you call `-[StringReceiver processData:]` you can call `-[StringReceiver string]` to get an updated string.

Comment: I already implemented the one you proposed. Because of user experience I want to show the strings obtained from the data as soon as possible( waiting all the data coming may take long )

Comment: Well that's why every time you call `-pocessData:`, you can call `-string`. In that way, you can show the user what you've got **after every update**.

Comment: Oh I may misunderstand what you proposed. This means every time I call "string" method I can get the string received so far...

Comment: Yes, I guess decoding incomplete data won't be a problem for `NSString`.

Comment: Thanks. This is one option.  Converting from NSData to NSString of same bytes repeatedly could cause performance problem but worth to try.